# Приключение по моей Эстонии

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, предлоги, существительные

Недавно в нашей семье приобрели для ребенка книжку ["Приключение по моей Эстонии"](https://rus.err.ee/904964/novaja-interaktivnaja-kniga-znakomit-detej-s-jestoniej-cherez-razlichnye-zadanija) (тираж — 20 тысяч на эстонском языке, 8 тысяч на русском).

Мы с дочерью "разоссорились в пух" из-за названия.
Я считаю, что говорить ***приключение по Эстонии*** неграмотно — надо или "приключение в...", или "путешествие по..." (в словарях подтверждения не нашла — только "чую").
Дочь считает, что все нормально.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разрешить наш спор:
можно ли говорить *приключение по стране, приключение по городу*?

Answer (score 3):

**Согласно словарю,** основное значение слова ***приключение*** — это случай, происшествие. Тогда название книги будет читаться как "Происшествие по моей Эстонии", а это неверно.

Книгу надо назвать "Путешествие по моей Эстонии".

Если она связана с приключениями детей, то можно это как-то обозначить, например: ***Веселое (необыкновенное)  путешествие по моей Эстонии.***

**Приключения** — это происшествия, разные случаи, которые обычно происходят **во время путешествия по различным местам**.

Если путешествовать по городу, по стране, то приключения будут называться так: приключения (где?) в городе, в стране.

**Примеры:**

Фильм «Невероя́тные приключе́ния италья́нцев в Росси́и».

«Приключения в Изумрудном городе» — российский детский  мультфильм.

Comment: Согласен с ответом, но хотел бы уточнить по поводу выражения "приключение по дороге на речку". Мне оно слух не режет. Правда, обстоятельство здесь какое-то странное: то ли времени, то ли места. Возможно, подобные примеры и расшатывают нормы в разговорной речи.

Comment: Здесь обстоятельство места  приобретает обобщенное значение, сближается с обстоятельством времени (= когда мы шли на речку).Сама дорога как конкретное место не важна, можно сказать по пути на речку.

Answer (score 3):

Это ошибка, конечно. Ошибка переводчиков.  Дело в том, что у автора ошибки нет, Кятлин Вайнола так определила жанр своей книги - приключение. Это книга приключений по теме "Эстония".

Вот в "Новостях" эстонского телевидения:

> Эстония: Состоялась презентация книги «Приключение «По моей Эстонии»

http://newsvideo.su/video/10192515

https://www.mke.ee/novosti-pbk/sostoyalas-prezentatsiya-knigi-priklyuchenie-po-moej-estonii

Так что верхняя строчка - жанр - книга-приключение, а две другие - название "По моей Эстонии".

В книге же задания для детей и родителей, это их приключения.

Comment: Думаю, что это действительно ошибка переводчика. В эстонском варианте книга носит название **Minu Eesti Seiklus** — без каких-либо точек или кавычек. https://www.raamatuvahetus.ee/et/book.book.html?id:=U00044159 Если правильно перевести, то название, возможно, должно быть таким: **Мое эстонское приключение**. То, что пишется в новостной презентации, — просто попытка завуалировать зту ошибку. Вот ТАК и живем.

Comment: И ещё. Ваше предложение **Это книга приключений по материалам Эстонии** кажется мне не совсем удачным — оно воспринимается двояко. 1. Это книга [приключений] по материалам Эстонии. 2. [Это книга] приключений по материалам Эстонии. Возможно, я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Comment: Я имела в виду именно "книга приключений", так автор сама называла свою книгу, я по сайтам посмотрела. Я эту книгу не видела наяву, а другие, русские, с весёлыми и необычными заданиями для читателя, видела, там действительно поставлен жанр - книга приключений, поэтому я и не удивилась фразе в новостях.

Comment: Ещё раз простите, но мне не понравилось Ваше _русское_ предложение: _Это книга приключений **по материалам** Эстонии._ Книга — по материалам. Мне эта фраза кажется неправильной.

Comment: Конечно, лучше будет смотреться  по теме "Эстония".